# Matplotlib change marker border color AND custom marker styles

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, markers

I am trying to plot a scatter plot in Matplotlib using colors from a list of colors. The code is here:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
from random import shuffle
rcParams['legend.numpoints'] = 1

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,28),columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZab'))

markers = []
for m in Line2D.markers:
    try:
        if len(m) == 1 and m != ' ':
            markers.append(m)
    except TypeError:
        pass
cust = [r'$\lambda$',r'$\bowtie$',r'$\circlearrowleft$',r'$\clubsuit$',r'$\checkmark$',r'$\spadesuit$']
styles = markers + cust
shuffle(styles)

color=['magenta','blue','green','none','brown','red']

for i,column in enumerate(df.iloc[:,1:7]):
    plt.plot(df['A'], df.iloc[:,i], linestyle='None', marker=styles[i], markersize=10, label=column, mfc=color[i], markeredgewidth=1.5)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The output is attached here.[image]

The problem is that the order of colors in the legend is not the same as the order of colors in the list.

I am expecting the following order of colors:
- magenta, blue, green, none, brown, red

**Questions:**

1. The order of colors in the plot is not the same as what I specified
   in the list. Is it possible to fix the code so that the colors are
   in the same order? (NOTE: If the marker has no face, then I want the marker edge to have the color from the list)
2. From the custom marker list `cust = [r'$\lambda$',r'$\bowtie$',r'$\circlearrowleft$',r'$\clubsuit$',r'$\checkmark$',r'$\spadesuit$']`, are there more options similar to this? i.e. how can I see a list of similar markers?

**EDIT:**
Here is the resulting plot by commenting out the list of marker styles [i.e. I commented out this line: `shuffle(styles)]`.
[image]

Comment: Well your first marker has no facecolor (is only composed of lines), thus you don't see anything in magenta. The rest works as expected.

Comment: Thanks. I added a second image showing the same plot without shuffling the list of markers. In this plot, the color or markers D, E and F are wrong. I realize that these do not have a facecolor - in this case, is it possible to have the line color follow the order from the list of colors? i.e. the line color for markers D, E and F would be  green, none, brown respectively. Is this possible?

Comment: @WR - Are you looking for the `markeredgecolor` (or in its shorter form, `mec`) kwarg?  As for the second part of your question regarding custom markers: Those are latex strings. There's no exhaustive list. You can use things like `r'$\frac{\gamma^2}{\alpha^{\cos(x)}}$'` or some other complex expression as a marker. Symbols like `r'$\clubsuit$'` just happen to be defined as well.